# Parallax js not working... image not showing

Tags: jquery, css, parallax.js

Using the suggested markup, css is correct, but absolutely no image is showing. When I use regular img tag (i.e.: `<img src="*"/>`) image shows perfectly... please help, im totally stumped and this thing is supposed to be so easy. Here's my code:

```
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-position="top" data-bleed="10" data-image-src="AE.jpg" data-natural-width="1920" data-natural-height="1000" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

css:

```
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Im running jquery 1.11.1 and foundation

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think we're missing some vital code here. where are the actual images? doesn't parallax work with a `ul` and all the layers inside `li`'s?

Comment: well, i'm referencing this git: http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/...

Comment: Ah that helps :) there's more parallax.js'es appearantly. if you run your page and open up an inspector, can you see the `parallax-mirror` elements, and do they have the proper image inside them?
If so, are there any elements with a background color (or non-transparent background) *above* your `parallax-window` element?

Comment: no mirrors but no js errors either... i don't think anything has a background-color specified but the body tag... the library doesn't seem to need initialization on document.ready either... (sigh) another 2 day puzzle to unravel.

Comment: an absence of divs with `parallax-mirror` class would point to the javascript not being executed...

Comment: Yeah I know but even in the demo page code there's no initialization for the library...

Comment: @pjldesign, did you manage to solve this issue as I've come across it just now where the same code works fine on one server, but not the other and I can't pinpoint where the issue is as there are no errors in the console...

Answer (score 3):

You need to set as below

```
.parallax-mirror {
    z-index:1
}
```

Comment: The .parallax-mirror element is coming up behind the body element. Are you using the Zurb Foundation CSS framework?

Answer (score 0):

Another issue for image not showing when the plugin is working perfectly is the background colour of a parent element.

In my case, it was a parent container that was wrapped around the entire body content area which had a `background: #fafafa!important`

Once I removed the background colour and applied it to only the divs that need it issue was solved and parallax image works.

Answer (score 0):

In default bootstrap

```
body { background-color: #fff; }
```

change it to

```
body { background-color: transparent; }
```

It will work.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the attribute `data-img-src` to `data-src`.

This solve my problem.